# TStringList descendant with id and subid for each element

Tags: delphi, data-structures, delphi-xe

I need to create a descendant of TStringList class, which has the same functionality as TstringList class, but for each string/object from the list to have an id and subid elements.

Is this possible by inheriting the TStringList class, or I need to create a new class and implement the behavior I need.

LE: I also need the Objects property, so I can not store in the list a pointer to a structure.

Comment: Do you need to search the stringlist via the id and subid elements?

Comment: Yes, but for this I can do a control loop.

Comment: Re:LE: you *can* re-use inherited Objects property and provide new GetObjects/SetObjects to re-implement it onto outside :-)

Comment: You should use TList<T> where T is your record containing all data associated with a single item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From inspecting the TStringList class source, I think it is possible to inherit the TStringList class directly, by adding another `FListIDs: PStringItemListIDs` (similar to the `FList: PStringItemList`) where `TStringItemIDs` is a record of `FID, FSubID: Integer` (assuming data type is Integer).

Next you need to override each `TStringList` method that involves `FList` i.e.: `Add`, `Clear`, `Delete`, `Insert`, etc... where you will handle `FListIDs` being added or removed.

Finally create index properties: `ID`, `SubID` with getter and setter functions. e.g:

```
property ID[Index: Integer]: Integer read GetID write SetID;
property SubID[Index: Integer]: Integer read GetSubID write SetSubID;
```

The getter and setter functions will get or set `FListIDs`.

Comment: i'd made a 'record of FID, FSubID, FStringListID' - while we may hope, that if accurately initialized the same way, string list and extra data list would behave the same, it is hard to warrant that, especialyl concerning possible future changes.

Answer (score 0):

How large data in ID and SubID is ?

AFAIR TStrings may have objects associated, and TObjects is a 32-bit pointer that, providing proper typecasts implemented, data can be stick to it directly.

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Classes.TStrings.Objects

Or you may use it like pointer to record {ID, SubID, TObject}.
Or you may use it as index in some array of those records or list of them, like TList< record ID, SubID, TObject end >

Then you would override new TObject setter/getter to actually dive into that record, and use ancestor's Objects geter/setter to hold index or pointer.

*PS. Maybe TDictionary<TPair<ID, SubID>, TPair< String, TObject>> would be useful as well to create TStrings interface from scratch.*

Comment: Data type for ID and SubId is Integer.

Comment: Problem with this solution is that I need the Objects property to behave in the same way as before. So I need also the list of the objects.

Comment: i noticed it's too late, but that is extendable to it.
you just need to override external Object setter/getter, relying on internal inherited methods to implement that mechanics. I updated the answer.

Comment: That would depend upon usage pattern - who is responsible of assigning ID and SubID,  can there be an item without those, etc.
You'd probably better implement Add(string, id, subid, object=nil) methods, if ID is caller-assignable and mandatory. On contrary, if ID is container-generated you may lazily allocate it on demand, in getter functions, keeping internal Object[i] nil for starters. All in all that comes rather close to @kobik's answer, with the difference that you do not need to override ALL the list-manipulating functions, but only implement lazy record allocator for new 6 get/setters.